# Modify response header in CefSharp

Tags: .net-core, cefsharp

I figured this was going to be a straight forward exercise via a [ResourceRequestHandler](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/104.4.x/html/T_CefSharp_Handler_ResourceRequestHandler.htm) and overriding the [OnResourceResponse](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/104.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_ResourceRequestHandler_OnResourceResponse.htm).

But the implementation throws `NotSupportedException: IResponse is read-only and cannot be modified. Check IResponse.IsReadOnly to guard against this exception`, if I try to manipulate the `Headers` or even if I try to call `SetHeaderByName` on the [IResponse](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/104.4.x/html/T_CefSharp_IResponse.htm)

I found [this](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2785) Cef issue, so I figure it is a Cef limitation. Is this correct ?

I also had a look at if it might be possible to implement a custom [IResourceHandler](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/104.4.x/html/T_CefSharp_IResourceHandler.htm) and  manipulate the response headers via `GetResponseHeaders`method, but any discussion of this Interface online seems to refer around handling requests, not responses.

Can it be done with an `IResourceHandler` ? Are there some examples ?

Comment: As you've discovered CEF doesn't currently support modifying response headers. Using an IResourceHandler means you have to make the network request using the built in .Net libraries (or similar). The example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/WebRequestResourceHandler.cs should give you a rough idea.

Comment: Great, at least there is a workaround

Comment: Potentially you can disable CEFs network interceptor and use the DevTools protocol. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-continueResponse I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: Did think of this, tanks for the heads up on needing to disable the network interceptor.